# I am unable to get last date that is max(reservation_date) from below query.Also query is taking much time

Tags: sql, oracle12c

My below query is taking long time.I don't know where I am doing wrong.Desire output
Resort_name
Resource_name 
last_date("it's booked in the reservation")
Arrival date of that reservation

```
    SELECT
    max(rsv.reservation_date),
    r.name    AS resort_name,
    rsv.name   AS resource_name,
    rsv.reservation_date,
    rv.arrival_date
FROM
    resorti18n           r
    JOIN resourcebasei18n     re ON ( r.resort_id = re.resort_id )
    JOIN reservedresourcebase rsv ON (rsv.resource_id=re.resource_id)
    JOIN reservation          rv ON ( rv.resort_id = re.resort_id )
    JOIN admin_organisation   ao ON ( ao.admin_organisation_id = r.admin_organisation_id )

WHERE
    rsv.type = 'producttype'
    group by 
    r.name,
    rsv.name,
    rsv.reservation_date,
    rv.arrival_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

use row_number()

```
 with cte as(SELECT
    rsv.reservation_date,
    row_number() over(partition by  r.name,rsv.name order by rsv.reservation_date desc) rn,
    r.name    AS resort_name,
    rsv.name   AS resource_name,
    rsv.reservation_date,
    rv.arrival_date
FROM
    resorti18n           r
    JOIN resourcebasei18n     re ON ( r.resort_id = re.resort_id )
    JOIN reservedresourcebase rsv ON (rsv.resource_id=re.resource_id)
    JOIN reservation          rv ON ( rv.resort_id = re.resort_id )
    JOIN admin_organisation   ao ON ( ao.admin_organisation_id = r.admin_organisation_id )

WHERE
    rsv.type = 'producttype'
 ) select * from cte where rn=1
```

usign subquery

```
select * from (SELECT
        row_number() over(partition by  r.name,rsv.name order by rsv.reservation_date desc) rn,
        r.name    AS resort_name,
        rsv.name   AS resource_name,
        rsv.reservation_date,
        rv.arrival_date
    FROM
        resorti18n           r
        JOIN resourcebasei18n     re ON ( r.resort_id = re.resort_id )
        JOIN reservedresourcebase rsv ON (rsv.resource_id=re.resource_id)
        JOIN reservation          rv ON ( rv.resort_id = re.resort_id )
        JOIN admin_organisation   ao ON ( ao.admin_organisation_id = r.admin_organisation_id )

    WHERE
        rsv.type = 'producttype'
     ) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: thanks fro you answer @Zaynul but I am new to sql and I m looking for more common query not so complex without 'with'

Comment: I am getting ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined error also can you please help me without  using partition by because this can be made by just changing in my above query.